# tuple index out of range database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to write a function that update the values in a database, but it give me a "tuple index out of range" error. I have the same amount of placeholders in the sql statement that in the tuple, but it still give me the same error. The error is in the updateValues function in the line 27. I will appreciate the help, i am new to python and programming per se and i am learning by trial and error.

This is the code of the class:

```
import sqlite3

class dbAccess():

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.filename = kwargs.get('filename')
    self.table = kwargs.get('table', 'grocery')

def sqlDo(self, sql, *params):
    self._db.execute(sql, params)
    self._db.commit()

def insertValues(self, db, item, cost, quantity):   
    self._db.execute('INSERT INTO {} (NAME, COST, QUANTITY) VALUES(?, ?, ?)'.format(self._table), (item, cost, quantity))
    self._db.commit()

def retrieveValues(self, ID):
    cursor = self._db.execute('select * from {} where name = ?'.format(self._table), (ID,))
    return dict(cursor.fetchone())

def updateValues(self, quantity, ID):
    self._db.execute('UPDATE {} SET QUANTITY = {} WHERE ID = {}'.format(self._table), (quantity, ID))
    self._db.commit()

def delete(self, ID):
    self._db.execute('delete from {} where t1 = ?'.format(self._table), (ID,))
    self._db.commit()

def calculateCost(self):
    cursor = self._db.execute('select name, cost * quantity from {}'.format(self._table))
    for v in cursor:
        print(dict(v))

def __iter__(self):
    cursor = self._db.execute('SELECT * FROM {} ORDER BY ID'.format(self._table))
    for row in cursor:
        yield(dict(row))


@property
def filename(self): return self._filename

@filename.setter
def filename(self, fn):
    self._filename = fn
    self._db = sqlite3.connect(fn)
    self._db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row  

@filename.deleter
def filename(self):
    self._filename.close()

@property
def table(self):
    return self._table
@table.setter
def table(self, t):
    self._table = t
@table.getter
def table(self):
    self._table = 'test'

def close(self):
    self._db.close()
    del self._filename


def main():
db = dbAccess(filename = 'test.db', table = 'test')

print('Create table test')
db.sqlDo('drop table if exists test')
db.sqlDo('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
                    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                    NAME TEXT, 
                    COST FLOAT, 
                    QUANTITY INTEGER)''')

print('Create rows')
db.insertValues('test', 'test1', 4.99, 5)
db.insertValues('test', 'test2', 7.99, 5)
for row in db: print(row)

print('Calculate Costs')
print(db.calculateCost())

print('Retrieve rows')
print(db.retrieveValues('test1'), db.retrieveValues('test2'))

print('Update rows')
db.updateValues(0, 1)
for row in db: print(row)

print('Delete rows')
db.delete('1')
for row in db: print(row)
```

if **name** == "**main**": main()

This is the output:

Create table test
Create rows
{'NAME': 'test1', 'QUANTITY': 5, 'ID': 1, 'COST': 4.99}
{'NAME': 'test2', 'QUANTITY': 5, 'ID': 2, 'COST': 7.99}
Calculate Costs
{'cost * quantity': 24.950000000000003, 'NAME': 'test1'}
{'cost * quantity': 39.95, 'NAME': 'test2'}
None
Retrieve rows
{'NAME': 'test1', 'QUANTITY': 5, 'ID': 1, 'COST': 4.99} {'NAME': 'test2', 'QUANTITY': 5, 'ID': 2, 'COST': 7.99}
Update rows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wilfredo\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\GroceryList\Grocery\dbAccess.py", line 103, in 
    if **name** == "**main**": main()
  File "C:\Users\Wilfredo\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\GroceryList\Grocery\dbAccess.py", line 96, in main
    db.updateValues(0, 1)
  File "C:\Users\Wilfredo\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\GroceryList\Grocery\dbAccess.py", line 27, in updateValues
    self._db.execute('UPDATE {} SET QUANTITY = {} WHERE ID = {}'.format(self._table), (quantity, ID))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing your format parameters correctly. For example look at one of the offending lines:

```
 self._db.execute('UPDATE {} SET QUANTITY = {} WHERE ID = {}'.format(self._table), (quantity, ID))
```

You'll have other errors for similar lines.

You should be formatting like so:

```
self._db.execute('UPDATE {} SET QUANTITY = {} WHERE ID = {}'.format(self._table, quantity, ID)
```

Comment: Problem solved thank you. I have another question, the other lines where formatted in the same way but they didn't present an error like the insertValues function is wrote in the same way that the updateValues function but it worked properly. What is different in the insertValues function that it worked at runtime?